# How to access variables of a class in another class without making them static?

Tags: java, swing, static, actionlistener

I am working on a Java Swing application and it has a `JFrame` which has array of `JButton`(Another class). I have variables in the `JFrame` which I want to access in the `JButton` when its `ActionListener` is called. Currently I am declaring those variables as `static` so that I can access them directly.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    //static variables
    public static MyButton buttons[] = new MyButton[N];
    public static int counter = 0;
    public static int clickedX, clickedY;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }

    public MyFrame(){
        // Doing Everything Here
        setSize(300, 380);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // Layout, JMenu etc.
    }

    //static functions to access static variables Here
}
```

Here is the `MyButton` class:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private int xID,yID;
    public MyButton(int x, int y) {
        addActionListener(this);
        xID = x;
        yID = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Accessing MyFrame static variables and functions here    
    }
}
```

But is there any other way to do this without declaring the variables and functions static?. I want to perform some logic based on the values in all buttons whenever `ActionListener` is invoked in any button

Note: I can't create `JFrame` object in the `JButton` class.

Comment: Note that the elements in the `buttons` array are never initialized, it only contains `null` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it like this:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //static variables
    private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[N];
    private int counter = 0;
    private int clickedX, clickedY;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }

    public MyFrame(){
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            b.addActionListener(this);
            buttons[i] = b;
        }
        // Doing Everything Here
        setSize(300, 380);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // Layout, JMenu etc.
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there any way to know which button is clicked?

Comment: @Vivek `e.getSource()` will return the button